# The Home Folder icon on the launcher will not open on Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher, home-directory

I have to usually open the home folder by pressing the super key, than typing *home* manually. It will work if i remove the icon from the launcher, then re add it. Is there a way to fix that? I am using *Ubuntu 11.10* with the *Unity* desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. If it doesn't, please file a bug. You can do that correctly by pressing alt+f2 and typing `ubuntu-bug unity`. Make sure you have upgraded your system before you do. You'll need to have an account at Launchpad.net, so if you don't have one, create one first.

However, I'm not sure you are aware, but when you've pinned an application to the launcher, you get separate keyboard shortcuts for them. For instance, if Nautilus is the first entry on your launcher, then you can start it or switch to it by pressing super+1. If you want to launch a new instance even if you already have one open, you can use super+shift+1. This works for 1-9 and you can use the numpad if you want to. For this reason, I always place my 4 absolutely most used applications on 1-4 since I can then switch using my left hand only. For the rest of them, I use the numpad.